# `data.table` how to get `keyby` to include all combinations of factors?

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have a `data.table` and I would like to count the occurrence of each combination of `a` and `b`:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  b = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2) %>% letters[.]
)
#    a b
# 1: 1 a
# 2: 1 a
# 3: 1 b
# 4: 1 b
# 5: 2 a
# 6: 2 a
# 7: 2 a
# 8: 2 a
# 9: 3 a
# 10: 3 b
# 11: 3 b
# 12: 3 b
dt1[, .N, keyby = .(a, b)]
#    a b N
# 1: 1 a 2
# 2: 1 b 2
# 3: 2 a 4
# 4: 3 a 1
# 5: 3 b 3
```

It misses out the case of `a==2 & b=="b"`, which has a zero count in `dt1`, but I want it to be included so the result would look like:

```
#    a b c
# 1: 1 a 2
# 2: 1 b 2
# 3: 2 a 4
# 4: 2 b 0
# 5: 3 a 1
# 6: 3 b 3
```

The most intuitive way to use the loop or the `apply` family but it is just inefficient for my large datasets. Any idea?

Comment: `c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2) %>% letters[.]` +1 for this great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tidyr/dplyr approach:

```
dt1 %>% 
  group_by(a,b) %>% 
  summarise(c = length(.)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  complete(a,b, fill = list(c = 0))
```

Comment: Could you please explain about `fill` is it `summarise`'s keyword? how it is working actually, could you please elaborate.

Comment: Complete is a wrapper of dplyr::left_join but it is tidyr function. You may pass fill value and replace NA's with it. In this case NA's replaced by 0.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sure, so NAs will be replaced with `0` what does `list(c=0)` do?

Comment: There could be more columns you may want to replace NA's so you put here those columns.